# refreshApex() is refreshing the data but is not invoking the function decorated with wire

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, refreshapex

An LWC component uses wire service to make a callout to an external system during page load. Users are able to refresh the data by clicking the Refresh button on the UI, which invokes **handleRefresh()**.

**refreshApex()** method below is updating the cached data, however the code block within the serverResponse method is not getting executed. I need **processResponse()** to be executed each time the data refreshed. Am I missing something or is this the expected behavior?

(processResponse() can be called from within handleRefresh() after the refresh, but I assume it's not the ideal approach.)

Thank you in advance!

```
    _wiredResult;

    @wire(getDetails, { recordId: "$recordId"})
       serverResponse(result) {
         this._wiredResult = result;
         const { data, error } = result;
         if (data) {
           console.log('DATA!');
           this.parsedResponse = data;
           this.processResponse();
    
         } else if (error) {
           console.error('ERROR DETAILS:', error);
         }
      }


    handleRefresh() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        refreshApex(this._wiredResult)
    }
```

----- UPDATE -----

When I add a pseudo parameter "cachingParam" to the method and update it with each refresh, the code block is executed as expected. I don't understand why it's behaving this way.

```
//updated wire method with an additional argument
@wire(getPolicyDetails, { recordId: "$recordId", cachingParam: "$cachingParam"})
..
..
..

 // cachingParam value is changed with each Refresh button click
 handleRefresh() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.cachingParam = this.cachingParam + 1;
    refreshApex(this._wiredResult)
 }
```

Comment: `console.log('DATA!');` isn't being executed?

Comment: Wire can be problematic and sometimes it works in such a way that it does not work. I always try to avoid it and call apex methods imperatively.

Comment: Yes @NickCook, console.log('DATA!') isn't being executed.